# Guava: Throwables.propagate and InterruptedException

Tags: java, exception, guava, interrupted-exception

what is the best practice for handling `InterruptedException`s when using Throwables.propagate(e) in Guava?

I love using `throw Throwables.propagate(e)`, especially in methods that throw no checked exceptions and where exception handling is the responsibility of the caller. But it doesn't do what I'd expect with InterruptedException.

I don't want to lose the fact that the thread was interrupted, so I end up writing things like:

```
public void run() {
    Callable c = ...;
    try {
        c.call();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw Throwables.propagate(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw Throwables.propagate(e);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this in Guava? Is there a (backwards compatible?!) way to use something like Throwables.propagate() that sets the thread as interrupted, if it is wrapping and propagating an InterruptedException?

Comment: I would raise this as a feature request within Guava

Answer (score 8):

Conveniently, we discussed this internally a while back. I'll just copy and paste:

My hard-line opinion on `Throwables.propagate(e)` is that it's basically `throw new RuntimeException(e)` and that people usually shouldn't do it, just as they usually shouldn't write `throw new RuntimeException(e)`.  (And if they're going to write it, they might as well write it directly so that it's clear what's going on.)

My hard-line opinion on `catch (Exception e)` -- usually how people get themselves into this mess -- is that they usually shouldn't do that, either.  (Obviously there are cases in which `catch (Exception e)` is obviously the right thing to do (basically any top-level, operation-scope catch block), but those are... obvious.)

My hard-line opinion on `InterruptedException` is that having `InterruptedException` implement `Exception` at all is broken in exactly this way: It requires special handling that other exceptions don't.

My hard-line opinion on converting `InterruptedException` to a `RuntimeException` is "don't."  (This, like much of the other stuff I've said above, is controversial.)

So on the one hand, I'm not sure there's anything we can do to salvage `propagate()`.  On the other hand, maybe it's nice to make the method a little less bad.

Then again, consider this caller, which catches `ExecutionException e`:

`throw Throwables.propagate(e.getCause());`

It would be wrong to interrupt the consumer thread, just as it would be wrong to throw `e.getCause()` directly, because the interruption was intended for the computing thread, not the consumer thread.

I'm inclined to leave `propagate()` alone.  (As you can probably guess, I'm personally inclined to deprecate it, but that's a bigger discussion.)

Comment: +1 interesting points. I'm amazed that people write `throw Throwables.propagate(e.getCause());`! The stack trace would look like everything happened in a single thread!

Comment: Thanks, interesting points. 

+1 to InterruptedException implementing Exception being wrong, but Java is where it is.

I think converting InterruptedException to a RuntimeException is sometimes essential: if my method signature is fixed by an external interface (so I can't throw InterruptedException), and my operation was interrupted (so I can't fulfil my contract), I must throw an exception. What other sensible option is there other than setting the thread as interrupted and throwing a RuntimeException?

Comment: For writing `throw new RuntimeException(e)` instead, it's annoying noise to have an exception wrapping the exception (especially when it's not adding anything useful, such as an additional message about the current context). Wherever that noise can be avoided (e.g. it's already an unchecked exception) then great.

There's a school of thought that APIs should use unchecked exceptions wherever possible. Even if one doesn't buy that argument, one still has to implement other people's interfaces written in that way.

So please don't deprecate `Throwables.propagate(e)`!

Comment: I think it is far better to `throw Throwables.propagate(e);` than to add the exception to the method signature when you deal with an API that throws a checked exception that you don't want to handle specifically. I think it is a good idiomatic way of saying "Nothing specific here, treat it as a normal execution problem".